Android apps centered around cars
I am looking for an Android and personal computer application that does all of the following, within, one nice application.
It covers, through schemas contained in lists and also though practical, touch-screen supported, games, all that is covered and taught, or, that can be taught, in the following:

driving schools

types of accidents, how they might, in bad situations, arise, their context (based, on real life, situations, and their solutions). Imagine, if this, could be designed, and taught, in a way to provide driver awareness and engagement with good behavior while driving

dos and don't s

another part of the app is about user cases of stuff that happens to the car (how it breaks down, when it breaks down). What the mechanic must do to fix it

another part is about mechanics coming up with solutions: to build cars, in innovative, and creative, manners

another part is about engineers designing cars

another part is about factories, implementing, car engineering design

another part is about road design, maintenance, and repairing


...
This would be a complex app with many parts, which could hopefully also have a personal computer application counterpart.
Who would be willing to implement such an app?
Where can I find such an app?
I would like to encourage the development of such an app, it would be very useful, and help people integrate their thoughts with car/car-centered life.

"Who would be willing to implement such an app?" What do you pay? It's always a question about money.

I think it could be a nice 50$ app on the Google Play store

Sure, many people (would purchase, it
